# why the value assignment j = i +1 in the second for loop doesn't work correctly

Tags: c

I got this weird behavior: in the following `for`-loop I'd find the same char in the string text and gather them together (e.g. "bdsabgs" -> "bbssdga"). The problem I got is in the second `for`-loop that in the second iteration when `i = 1`, the value `j` doesn't start from 2 but from some ridiculas value (e.g. 2860) . Could anybody explain me why and the possible solution for that? Thank you in advance!

```
    for (int i = 0; text[i+1] != '/0'; i++)
    {
         for (int j = i + 1; text[j] != '/0'; j++)
         {            
                if (text[i] == text[j])
                {
                    temp = text[j];
                    text[j] = text[i + 1];
                    text[i + 1] = temp;

                    break;

                }
          }


     }
```

Comment: `'/0'` is not the NULL terminator

Comment: `int j = i + 1;` in your loop will work to set `j` to 1 more than `i` until you run out of numbers in your int, your issue is elsewhere.

Comment: Please also provide the definition of the text array. Otherwise your example is not fully reproducible. Also `temp` is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `/0` symbol is just the wrong one. It should be `\0`, then everything should work as expected:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char text[] = "this is my text";
    int i,j,temp;
    for (i = 0; text[i+1] != '\0'; i++) {
         for (j = i + 1; text[j] != '\0'; j++) {            
                if (text[i] == text[j]) {
                    temp = text[j];
                    text[j] = text[i + 1];
                    text[i + 1] = temp;
                    break;
                }
          }
     }
     printf("my text: %s", text);
     return 0;
}
```

Output: `my text: tttssii   mhexy`

Answer (score 1):

Okay you have some issues in your code.

This works:

```
int main()
{
    char text[20]="bdsabgs";
    char temp;
    for (int i = 0; text[i+1] != '\0'; i++)
    {
         for (int j = i + 1; text[j] != '\0'; j++)
         {            
                if (text[i] == text[j])
                {
                    temp = text[j];
                    text[j] = text[i + 1];
                    text[i + 1] = temp;

                    break;

                }
          }
     }
    printf("%s\n", text);

    return 0;
}
```

Result: bbssdga

As an aside its not good practice to run loops where the termination condition may not be met. I would suggest that maybe you use a `while {…}` and use both `'\0'` and `sizeof(text)` as termination conditions, or run `strlen` on text first and use that.

Comment: Yes that's it the '\0'! Thank u!